# Getting "LaTeX Error: File `tempora.sty' not found."

Tags: latex

I am getting "LaTeX Error: File `tempora.sty' not found." I suppose a tex package needs to be installed. Which one?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt install texlive-fonts-extra`

will install a number of extra font packages. After installation the sty file may be available at

`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tempora/tempora.sty`